# Google Account ID?

Tags: php, api

I am building an app on top of Google Reader. Since users have to enter their Google Account data, I'd like to use this data to assign personal settings to each user.

However, if I do so and a user would change his email adress or password(for the whole Google Account), I wouldn't be able to identify him anymore.

Thus, I need to know if there's a Google Account ID or something that I can use to identify users regardless of an email adress or password.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Given Reader is shutting down in two months, is this wise?

Answer (score 5):

If you use the Google Account API, you can connect the user to your app using OpenID or OAuth. Both methods return an account ID which stays static for that user.

More information: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/